# how to make svg hover effects in css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The hover effect is not working:

```js
function changeColor() {
  const buttonBg = document.getElementById("button-bg");
  const newColor = getRandomColor();
  buttonBg.setAttribute("fill", newColor);

  // Remove the class and re-add it to trigger the animation again
  buttonBg.classList.remove("change-color-animation");
  void buttonBg.offsetWidth; // Force reflow
  buttonBg.classList.add("change-color-animation");
}

function getRandomColor() {
  const letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```css
/* CSS Styles for the button */
.svg-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.svg-button:hover {
  background-color: purple;
}

/* Animation for the button color change */
@keyframes changeColorAnimation {
  0% {
    fill: blue;
  }
  50% {
    fill: green;
  }
  100% {
    fill: red;
  }
}

.change-color-animation {
  animation: changeColorAnimation 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>SVG Button</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="svg-button" onclick="changeColor()">
      <!-- SVG for the button -->
      <svg width="100" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect id="button-bg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="blue" />
        <text x="25" y="30" fill="white">Click Me</text>
      </svg>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

HERE IS THE LINK TO MY UNADULTERATED CODE: https://github.com/Newton5000/svg-example

I tried asking AI but i was not successful.Although the colors are working in terms of changing after clicking, the hover is not working.i also got the code from AI.its only a practice so you can be sure we are only working with that button only

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on here? Also might be useful to include what you've tried so far to fix the problems you are facing.

Comment: `the hover is not working` What is it supposed to do on hover?

Comment: I added your code in the question itself. You can delete it if you don't want this. It better to learn things gradually. Begin with simple things, and build up from there. Using A.I. to learn to program is not the best way to go about it. It dumps you in the deep end without a way out, and you learn/understand very little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google looks like you have it right.
https://css-tricks.com/change-color-of-svg-on-hover/

Your style file has an extra s in it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
```

---

**Your css file is named style.css.**

---

Answer (score 3):

to change the button's background color on hovering, you should edit your selector as this:

```
.svg-button svg rect:hover {
  fill: purple;
}
```